# How to show cell value different from the store records of tree panel in extjs?

Tags: spring, extjs

I am using extjs 6.0.1 as front end and spring as backend code in my project. I have one UI or page the use the tree panel to show the data. 
Below are the store and model code.

```
Ext.define('SomeTreeStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
model: 'SomeTreeModel',
autoSync: false,
autoLoad: false,
root: {
    id: 0,
    expanded: false,
    description: 'SomeData'
},
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    writer: {
        writeAllFields: true,
        allowSingle: false,
        rootProperty: 'children',
        clientIdProperty: 'clientId'
    },
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        rootProperty: 'children',
        successProperty: 'success'
    },
    api: {
        create: 'rest/test/adddata',
        read: 'rest/test/getdata',
        update: 'rest/test/updatedata',
        destroy: 'rest/test/deletedata'
    },
    headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
    }
}
});


Ext.define('SomeTreeModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.TreeModel',
idProperty: 'id',
identifier: 'negative',
fields: [
    { name: 'id', type: 'int' },

    { name: 'item', type: 'string' },
    { name: 'data1', type: 'string' },
    { name: 'data2', type: 'number' },
    { name: 'unit', type: 'string' },
    { name: 'Rate', type: 'number' },
    { name: 'Amount', type: 'number' }
]
});
```

I have to show the rate and amount on the base of unit. 
eg. if unit == PM then only I have to show the rate and amount value in the tree panel otherwise I have to show the blank value or nothing.

For same I use below code.

```
{
    text: 'Amount',
    flex: 1.5,
    sortable: false,
    dataIndex: 'Amount',
    align: 'right',
    renderer: function (value, metaData, record, rowIdx, colIdx, store, view) {

        if(record.get('unit') == 'PM'){
            return Ext.util.Format.number(value, '0.00');
        }else{
            return '';
        }
    }

}
```

But this code will update the store value also. And whenever I update something it will update the database with blank value for rate and amount.

And I also have to allow to update rate and Amount on the base of the unit value.

Please give me the way to show the treepanel value different from the store value.

Answer (score 1):

How about this code?
To avoid binding between cell value and store, doesn't use dataIndex property.

```
{
    text: 'Amount',
    flex: 1.5,
    sortable: false,
    //dataIndex: 'Amount',
    align: 'right',
    renderer: function (value, metaData, record, rowIdx, colIdx, store, view) {

        if(record.get('unit') == 'PM'){
            //return Ext.util.Format.number(value, '0.00');
            return Ext.util.Format.number(record.get('Amount'), '0.00');
        }else{
            return '';
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**
I forgot to consider

> And I also have to allow to update rate and Amount on the base of the
>   unit value.

You have to update the store value manually, like below.

```
{
    text: 'Amount',
    flex: 1.5,
    sortable: false,
    //dataIndex: 'Amount',
    align: 'right',
    renderer: function (value, metaData, record, rowIdx, colIdx, store, view) {

        if(record.get('unit') == 'PM'){
            var FormattedAmount = Ext.util.Format.number(record.get('Amount'), '0.00');
            record.set('Amount', FormattedAmount);  // Update the store manually.

            return FormattedAmount;
        }else{
            return '';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Yasuyuki Uno it's work. but there is one problem with this code if I update the value of gross rate and gross amount it will not affect in store. Have you any idea how to get updated value and set it into the store? I am new in extjs may be this thing will small for you.

Comment: @AnkitJain Because of I'm not good at English, I'm not sure understanding correctly...
Anyway I updated answer. Hope it works and helps.